# How do I use Topshelf to host ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack, topshelf

I'm trying to selfhost ServiceStack in Topshelf, but keep getting an error:

> Only Uri prefixes ending in '/' are allowed.

Using the ServiceStack templates for a Windows service works but not the Topshelf.

My Apphost.cs looks like this:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase  
{  
    public AppHost(): base("My test", typeof(MyServices).Assembly) { }  
    public override void Configure(Container container) { }  
}
```

And then using it like this: (Thanks to https://gist.github.com/miketrebilcock)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var appSettings = new AppSettings();
    AppConfig config = new AppConfig(appSettings);

    HostFactory.Run(x => {
        x.UseLog4Net();
        x.Service<AppHost>(s => {
            s.ConstructUsing(name => new AppHost());
            s.WhenStarted(ah => { ah.Init(); ah.Start(config.hostname); });
            s.WhenStopped(ah => ah.Stop());
        });

        x.RunAsLocalSystem();
        x.SetDescription("My App Description (" + config.appURL + ")");
        x.SetDisplayName("My App Name");
        x.SetServiceName("MyApp");
        x.StartAutomatically();
    });
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which line are you getting the error message? What is the value of config.appURL?

Comment: Value of the url is "http://localhost:8088/", the line "s.WhenStarted" and the "apphost.Start()" gives the error.

Comment: A URI prefix string is composed of a scheme (http or https), a host, an optional port, and an optional path. An example of a complete prefix string is "http://www.contoso.com:8080/customerData/". **Prefixes must end in a forward slash ("/").** [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6). Make sure your config.hostname ends with a forward slash("/"). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however as you can see i have an "/" at the end in my url, "localhost:8088/".

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I took another look at this in the weekend and found out that it was a missing "/". The config file were never read in a proper way and a default value was missing the forward slash.

Comment: Cool you figured it out!